# Chrome sometimes hides navigation layer

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome

2 sites - same WordPress theme - when viewed with Chrome - 2 separate results:

*URLS have been removed.*

GOOD: blog site (notice the menu navigation in the gold container)
BAD: parent site  (if you look quick you'll see the navigation before it disappears)

The issue seems to be some sort of stacking issue. I've copied the same style-sheet over and still am having the same results after clearing cache and refreshing.

What's going on? 
Thanks for this forum.

The details: 
3 browser (IE, FF, Chrome)
2 blogs

1 theme (The Corporation - SAME stylesheet)

Issue:
When viewing parent site in Chrome, the navigation menu and the menu separator image(/wp-conten ... arator.png) is hiding under the /wp-conten ... r_tile.png background image.

More details:
Chrome version (Version 24.0.1312.56 m)

Wordpress versions:
main site (WordPress 3.2.1.)
blog site (WordPress 3.4.1)

Theme versions: TheCorporation 1.3

Yes, they are customized - but identical. I'm not a fan of customizing.

I did find this - not sure if it is related:
code DOT google DOT com /p/chromium/issue ... ?id=154671

and...
news DOT ycombinator DOT com/item?id=4587264

BTW, same issue when viewing in Safari

Answer (score 2):

Your blog has less links in navigation so it easily fits next to the logo, but on the website you have more links and navigation goes below logo making it invisible.

Quick fix for this situation would be this CSS:

```
img#logo {
    margin: 6px 0 6px 20px;
}

div#top-menu {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Sweetness! I was looking at the code rather than the content. Thank you so much. It worked!